# Springboot application in pivotal Cloud with different environments

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I am using a Pivotal Cloud foundry with different testing environments (test, QA, UAT, PROD) Spring boot application
I have created multiple properties files(Each pointing to different db) like

```
application-dev.properties
application-test.properties
application-qa.properties
application-uat.properties
application-prod.properties
```

if it is in local i am running by seting `-Dspring.progiles.active=test/qa/uat/prod`

```sh
 mvn clean compile springboot:run -Dspring.progiles.active=test
```

How can I make it customize my application to use the specific properties file based on the environment in the cloud?
What all the configurations do I need to change? Below is my `application.properties` file.

```
spring.profiles.active=test

spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class =org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect
server.port=9090

logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO
logging.file=myapplication.log
```

or do I need to change whenever I move to higher environments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can have one `applicaiton.yml` file for all of your environments and separate environment-specific manifest file. Use spring profile feature to add environment-specific properties. Spring will auto pick the properties based on the active environment profile and manifest file.
Example application.yml can have

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:  default
  username: xyz

spring:
  profiles:  development
  username: abc
```

And in an environment-specific manifest file you can have:

```yaml
env:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: development
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to move all your property files to GIT by leveraging Spring Cloud Config Server. From your application, use bootstrap.yml file to connect with Config Server and you'll be providing the environment name like prod, dev, qa.

Comment: So, when ever i am pushing into new environment i need to modify my bootstrap.yml file ?
`applications:
- name: SampleProject
  memory: 1G
  instances: 1
  path: target\sampleProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  env:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: TEST `

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the environment, you can pass TEST as runtime as parameter to bootstrap.yml file.